# One liner for setting string based on a condition

Tags: javascript

Is there a more elegant way of writing this code ? I don't need IE support.

```
if (a == '')
{
  $('.some-class').html('');
}
else
{
  $('.some-class').html('Some Text');
}
```

I can only think of this :

```
$('.some-class').html(a == '' ? '' : 'Some Text');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty string `""` is a falsy value, thus you can do :

```
$('.some-class').html(a || "Some text");
```